# How to get unique instance id of azure function in python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to save some information (multiple rows) in database from Azure function (Python env.).

For this, I am looking for a unique identifier corr. to each run of azure function.

I have came across the word GUID at few places, but I cannot find any documentation on how to use this function or attribute in Azure Function Python environment.

Any help at earliest is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUID technology is not unique to Python Azure Function, it is a commonly used unique identifier which is generated based on the current time and computing machine, you can do this in python to generate it:

```
import uuid

print(uuid.uuid4())
```

In azure function, use below code to get it:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(context.invocation_id)
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is the GUID:" + context.invocation_id,
            status_code=200
    )
```

Let me know whether this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting the instance id using that. I just want to confirm that this id is unique and will not be repeated?

Comment: @SVB-knowmywork Yes, off course. This id is generate based on the current time and the current state of machine. Basically, it can be said that it will not be repeated in the real world. If you generate 1,000 GUIDs per second, it can't be possible to generate a duplicate GUID without trillions of years. If you generate 2^20 GUIDs every second, you need 50 trillion years to have a higher probability of making it repeat. I think your function does not have such a scale and will not run for such a long time, so it is completely reliable.